# control that event with integer number is not happening more than N times per second

Tags: c#

My system generates events with integer number. Totally there are about 10 000 of events from 1 to 10 000. Every time I receive new event with numer i need to check how many times I've already received event with such number in tha last second:

- if I have received this event more than ~3-10 times in last second than I need to ignore it
- otherwise i need to process it.

So I just need to control and ignore "flood" with events with the same number.

There are two requirements:

- overhead of the flood control should be really MINIMAL as it used in HFT trading
- at the same time i do not need to control "exactly" I just need "roughly" flood control. I.e. it's ok to stop receive events somewhere between 3 and 10 events per second.

So my proposal would be:

- create int[10 000] array
- every second refresh all items in this array to 0 (refresh operation of item of the array is atomic, also we can iterate over array without any problems and without locking because we do not insert or delete items, however probably someone can recomend special function to "zero" array, take into accout that I can read array at the same time from another thread)
- every time new event received we a) `Interlocked.Increment` corresponding item in the array and only if the result is less than a threshold (~3) we will process it.

So flood control would be just one `Intrerlocked.Increment` operation and one comparision operation.

What do you tnink can you recommend something better?

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your approach - is that if you clear the counters every second - it might be that you had a flood right before the end of the second but since you've just cleared it you will continue accepting new event.
It might be OK for you as you are good with approximation only.

Another approach may be to have an array of queues of time stamps.
When a new event comes in - you get the relevant queue from the array and clear from its head all the timestamps that occurred more than a second in the past.
The you check the size of the queue, if it is bigger than the threshold you do nothing - otherwise you enter the new event timestamp into the queue and process it.
I realize that this approach might be slower than just incrementing integers but it will be more accurate.

I suppose you can run some benchmarks and find out how slower is it and whether it fits your needs or not.

Comment: i'm afraid it will not be only slower, it requires new memery on the fly (which always not desired in HFT, it's better to use pre-allocated memory). of course circular-buffer can be used but i think my "average" algorithm described above is better because 1. it's fast. 2. it doesn't allocate memory while working. 3. i don't need "flood" control to be accurate, i just need to ignore "extreme" flood so it fits my needs.

Comment: You can always allocate object in advance and only assign the timestamp to them while processing (and after removing them from the queue return them to some 'unused objects' pool.

Comment: the question is how queue itself is implement. would it be "circular buffer" implemented as "array" or not.... anyway my approach looks simpler and faster...